# example of tensor product of three finitely generated R-modules that equal 0

Tags: modules

Can you give an example of a commutative unitary ring $R$ and three finitely generated $R$-modules $L$, $M$ and $N$ such that $L\otimes M\ne 0$, $M\otimes N\ne 0$, and $L\otimes N\ne 0$, but $L\otimes N\otimes N = 0$?

Comment: Why do you want to know? What have you tried, or looked up? etc

Comment: Can you give three numbers $m$, $n$ and $p$ such that $(m,n)\neq1$, $(n,p)\neq1$ and $(m,n,p)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mathbb{Z}/10\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/15\neq 0$,  $\mathbb{Z}/6\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/10\neq 0$,  $\mathbb{Z}/6\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/15\neq 0$, but $\mathbb{Z}/6\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/10 \otimes_{Z}\mathbb{Z}/15=\mathbb{Z}/2\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/15=0$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Uups, too quick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you're asking for $L,M,N$ such that 
$$
  L\otimes_R M \ne 0 \\
  M\otimes_R N \ne 0 \\
  N\otimes_R L \ne 0
$$
but $L\otimes_R M\otimes_R N=0$?

Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's hint is the way to go. Find integers $l,m,n$ such that $(l,m)$, $(m,n)$, and $(n,l)$ are larger than one but for which $(l,m,n) = 1$. The easiest way to do this is to choose distinct primes $p_i, 1\leqslant i\leqslant 3$ and put 
$$
  l = p_2 p_3 \\
  m = p_1 p_3 \\
 n = p_1 p_2 .
$$
Then $L=\mathbf Z/l$, $M=\mathbf Z/m$, and $N=\mathbf Z/n$ have the desired properties.

Comment: If Mariano's hint is the way to go, why did you feel it necessary to elaborate and thereby relieve the poster of any obligation to give this thing a moment's thought?

Comment: Mainly because Mariano's hint is not immediately correct.